# Page Factory @FindBy

Tags: selenium, page-objects

I am currently learning page object model (POM) and I am trying to access a specific web element using @FindBy but I am not sure how to correctly write the syntax for my element into @FindBy?

What I have is:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[dta-qid='inventory']");
```

So my question is how do I place `a[da-qid='inventory']` correctly into @FindBy?

---

Edit:

By, `a[da-qid='inventory']`, what I mean is that it selects every `<a>` element whose `da-qid` value begins with `'inventory'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@FindBy(css="a[dta-qid='inventory']")
```

I've used that kind of locators in my last project and it's worked like charm. I hope this is that You want :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is what I was look for.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an exact answer without seeing the full element, but the [official documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements) on selectors ought to help you out.

Comment: I have made an edit to my question. Does my edit help clarify?

Comment: For "begins with", there is a special selector. Check out this article and scroll down to the advanced section. https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

This syntax might help u check out.
@FindBy(locator="locator value")
private WebElement elementName;
Don't forget in POM we follow encapsulation concept

Comment: Hi @Anand welcome to SQA, We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.